# Need help with pdo_mysql and data mapper pattern

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo

I'm having issues with php-cgi.exe crashing while using php-pdo-mysql.dll.

I'm using the data mapper design pattern show in Padraic Brady's Zend Off The Deep End and everything has been working correctly.

I have a table which stores an ip address whitelist, and I'm able to access that properly via a mapper class using Zend_Db_Table.

I also have a admin_users table that is very simple, just the standard username, password, etc. The mappers classes are nearly identical. Both have complete unit test coverage.

The problem arises when I try and do a fetch all. the restrictionMapper fetchAll works great. The userMapper->fetchAll() keeps segfaulting. It crashes the FastCGI via the php_pdo_mysql.dll. Because I am segfaulting, I can't see any error messages, so I can't diagnose what is going on. The file dies on line 232 of Zend/Db/Staement/Pdo.php in Zend Framework 1.9.2.

Comment: Ok, I guess the problem has to do with differences in PDO between my Windows and Linux enviroment.  The code works in Linux, but not in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be several things, like the library version of the mysql lib, or mysql server. You can maybe try to updrade the PHP version or the libmysql.dll

Comment: I would reccoment downgrade :D There are new bug not fixed in new versions :D